# Folder Name Inside folder

Tags: linux, shell

I had a Folder `/home/user/backup`. So I want to run a shell script through which when I run the shell script first line will a java jar which will download files with date as folder name. so `/home/user/backup/datefolder`. So in that shell script itself after download of the folder I want to take that date folder and do compress(tar) which will be saved into another location. Can any one help me

Comment: There is nothing to help you with.

Comment: @redFIVE.. Iam new to linux script so I didn't have any sample lines

Comment: Thanks  so for I got this but I wnat cd into source folder and take the date folder and compress it with same folder name                                  `SourceFolder=/home/user/Backup
              RequiredFolder=echo "$SourceFolder"/*
              echo "$RequiredFolder"
              tar -zcvf "$RequiredFolder".tar.gz "$SourceFolder"`

Answer (score 1):

If your script.sh is elsewhere on your root use this:

`now=$(date)
mkdir /home/user/backup/$now
cd /home/user/backup
/*your download command*/
java -filename.jar > ./$now 
tar -cvzf /some/other/location/$now.tar.gz $now`

If you place your script.sh at /home/user/backup then use this:

`now=$(date)
mkdir $now
/*your download command*/
java -filename.jar > ./$now 
tar -cvzf /some/other/location/$now.tar.gz $now`

I hope this answers your question, if I understood your question correctly. I must say your question was not quite clear. You could have detailed it more clearly.